# Convert json text to PHP array for datatables childrow example

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, datatables

I am referencing this Data tables example https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html and trying to use PHP to generate the AJAX as used on the example.

Here is a snippet of the raw json code. If I paste this into my Ajax php code, it will render the correct data on my datatable.

```
{
"data": [
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Tiger Nixon",
  "position": "System Architect",
  "salary": "$320,800",
  "start_date": "2011/04/25",
  "office": "Edinburgh",
  "extn": "5421"
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Garrett Winters",
  "position": "Accountant",
  "salary": "$170,750",
  "start_date": "2011/07/25",
  "office": "Tokyo",
  "extn": "8422"
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "name": "Ashton Cox",
  "position": "Junior Technical Author",
  "salary": "$86,000",
  "start_date": "2009/01/12",
  "office": "San Francisco",
  "extn": "1562"
}
]
}
```

I used a json to PHP conversion tool to look at the correct format I should be writing it in, but when I add it inside my database loop, it just gives me the one row of data in the datatable. I would expect it to give me 3 rows. I'm pretty sure it's just because how I am initialising the $dataArray variable, but not sure how else to write it. Below is the PHP code I am using.

```
$sql1= "Select Top(3) * from Table where RouteStatus = 1";
$stmt1=sqlsrv_query( $mysq, $sql1);
$dataArray=array();
while( $row= sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) )    {
$dataArray=[
    "data" => [
        [
            "id" => $row['RouteHeaderID'],
            "name" => $row['BulkId'],
            "position" => $row['Heigh'],
            "salary" => "$320,800",
            "start_date" => "2011/04/25",
            "office" => "Edinburgh",
            "extn" => "5421"
        ]
    ]
];
}
```

echo json_encode($dataArray);

Answer (score 0):

You just rewrite every row for the same array key, use `[]` (adding new subarray) instead:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $dataArray['data'][] = [
    "id" => $row['RouteHeaderID'],
     "name" => $row['BulkId'],
     "position" => $row['Heigh'],
     "salary" => "$320,800",
     "start_date" => "2011/04/25",
     "office" => "Edinburgh",
     "extn" => "5421"
  ];
}
```

Comment: Please vote to close new duplicate questions instead of answering them.